# unable to resolve the identifier - C programming

Tags: c, netbeans, windows-7, mingw

I recently configured Netbeans for C/C++ and I am trying to write simple application which splits the strings by comma.

Although I am getting below error while using `strsep` and I have gone through various questions (on stackoverflow itself) but none of them sees to be helping.

`Unable to resolve identifier strsep.`

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: If you are using a toolset that includes strsep, did you use the correct `#include` to get it?  If not, see http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/43635/

Comment: There is no language C/C++!

Comment: @NathanOliver: Linux? You mean kernel? Otherwise it would be glibc, which is not restricted to Linux.

Comment: My bad.. I am working on windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strsep` is not part of the C standard library.

So you'll have to code it yourself, or find a version.

The closest equivalent to the "normal" `strsep` is `strtok`.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Actually I am java/c# programmer and I almost have no idea about how to parse the string array in C. and I have a quick task to do so in a day so searching for that. Also need to take care of memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

`strsep()` is BSD.

The GNU libc provides it if `#define`ing `_BSD_SOURCE`.

[Please find the Linux man-page to `strsep()`for reference here.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html)